# c# OrderBy string hierachy xx.xx.xx

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a list of object that I would like to sort using the Option.Numero_Reference property.

The thing is that Numero_reference is a string in the xx.xx.xx format

Is there a way the order them by group of xx?

Here is what a have done for now, witch doesn't work:

```
myList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Option.Numero_Reference)
.ThenByDescending(x =>   x.Option.Numero_Reference.Substring(x.Option.Numero_Reference.IndexOf(".")))
```

This code gives me something like:

- 3.9.6
- 3.9.2
- 3.8
- 3.7.2
- 3.6
- 3.17.5
- 3.17
- 3.16.4.7
- 3.11
- 3.10.1

When I'm supposed to have:

- 3.17.5
- 3.17
- 3.16.4.7
- 3.11
- 3.10.1
- 3.9.6
- 3.9.2
- 3.8
- 3.7.2
- 3.6

Has we can see, the basic string compare get it wrong with 10th after the first point.

Another thing is, the number of groups divided by points is variable and follow no rules.

Anyone can help?

**EDIT**

Here is the complete query with the Version solution:

```
context.Options.Join(context.Categories_Options,
 opt => opt.ID_Option,
 cat_opt => cat_opt.ID_Option,
 (opt, cat_opt) => new { Option = opt, Categories_Options = cat_opt })
 .Where(x => x.Categories_Options.ID_Categorie == catId)
 .OrderByDescending(x => new Version(x.Option.Numero_Reference))
 .Select(x => x.Option)
 .ToList();
```

This only gives me an empty list.

Comment: It gives you `empty list` because of the `Where` method, and that **doesnt'** involve `Version`, the `OrderByDescending` should work OK without filtering any elements out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the `Version` class which has built-in ordering:

```
myList.OrderByDescending(x => new Version(x.Option.Numero_Reference))
```

Comment: Since an IOrderedEnumerable is returned, a not more confusing solution would be:

myList = myList.OrderByDescending(x => new Version(x.Option.Numero_Reference)).ToList();

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Version` class to represent those strings, and the comparison method of `Version` should result in the sort that you are expecting, rather than based on lexicographic order.

```
myList.OrderByDescending(x => new Version(x.Option.Numero_Reference))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that there will never be more than four components, you can use the Version class as the other answers suggest. If there will be more than four components you can do one of the following:

- implement [`IComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer.aspx) and use the [overload of `OrderBy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx) that takes an IComparer
- Refactor so Numero_reference is a custom class (not just a string) and make the class extend [`IComparable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IComparable.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add this answer just for another reference. If your format does fit well with the format of a `Version` number, the other answers are the best, with this answer of mine, you just to know the maximum number of digits in each place (separated by the dots) and the maximum number of all the digits:

```
//this can be used for the format from XX to XX.XX.XX.XX.XX.XX
var result = myList.OrderByDescending(x => 
                    string.Join("",x.Option.Numero_Reference.Split('.')
                          .Select(a=>a.PadLeft(2,'0')).ToArray()).PadRight(12,'0'));
//You can replace the 2 and 12 to the maximum number you want.
```